# How to make the youtube video in Joomla article variable?

Tags: joomla, youtube, conditional-statements

I have training material consisting of multiple lessons (= YouTube video’s).
I want these to be played within one and the same Joomla article, so that the comments of all students / viewers are shared over all lessons/video’s of that training.

For each lesson the student receives an email with the url, which is the same for all lessons, but with a variable to drive the correct video.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an extension or a way to develop a solution with javascript and PHP ??

In the first case you can try the media gallery extension supplied in the Joomla! extension directory, but I'm not sure that you find what you looking for...

In the second case you can building something with a little combinaison of javascript and PHP. One way that you can follow :

insert the id of the video in the url who's sent to the student then start the video by triggering a click on the player of the video.